# Left align labels in itemize

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, itemize

I want my itemize environment to output something like

```
Email:     my@email.com

Address:   Street name
           City
           Country

Phone:     My phone number
```

I have tried using `\usepackage{enumitem}` and `\setitemize{leftmargin=*, align=left}` but the output is just

```
Email: my@email.com

Address: Street name
  City
  Country

Phone: My phone number
```

I could probably accomplish what I want with a table, but shouldn't it be possible to do the same with itemize?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another solution :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[align=parleft, labelsep=2cm,]
\item[test1:] premier item;
\item[Coucou:] deuxième item;\\
  line 2
\item[test\_auto:] troisième item.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Can I do something to make sure the labels are aligned with the margin of the page? Right now the labels are more left than the rest of the text on my page. If I use `leftmargin=*`, the `labelwidth` is ignored... I use `\setitemize{leftmargin=*, align=parleft, labelsep=2cm}` but some labels are too wide

Comment: You can use : \leftskip=

Answer (score 9):

You can simply modify some parameters of a `description` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[labelwidth=4em,leftmargin =\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep\relax, font=\sffamily\mdseries]
\item[Email:] my@email.com

\item[Address:] Street name\\
                    City\\
                    Country

\item[Phone:] My phone number
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You may want to use `tabbing`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
Address: \=\kill
Email:   \> my@email.com \\[1ex]
Address: \> Street name \\
         \> City \\
         \> Country \\[1ex]
Phone:   \> My phone number
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have to compile a directory, use `\\*` instead of `\\` so no page break can happen inside an entry.

It wouldn't also be difficult providing an interface such as

```
\personaldata{
  email   = my@email.com,
  address = Street name \\ City \\ Country,
  phone   = +55 555 555 5555,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Design own list! From "The LaTeX Companion":

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{calc}
    \usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\entrylabel}[1]{%
     \makebox[\labelwidth][l]{\parbox[t]{\labelwidth}{\raggedleft#1}}%
                             }% end of definition

\newenvironment{entry}[1]%
    {\begin{list}{}{%
        \renewcommand{\makelabel}{\entrylabel}%
        \settowidth{\labelwidth}{#1:~}%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth + \labelsep}
        \setlength{\listparindent}{2ex}%
        \setlength{\parsep}{0.2\baselineskip}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0.2\baselineskip}
    }}%
    {\end{list}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{entry}{Address:}
\item[e-mail:]      \href{mailto:my@email.com}{my@email.com}
\item[Address:]     Street name\\
                    City\\
                    Country
\item[Phone:]       My phone number
    \end{entry}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, similar result you can obtain with `enumitem`. In this case you need define adequate `labelwidth`.

Answer (score 0):

for this use can just use \item[•]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
\item[Email:]       my@email.com

\item[Address:]     Street name\\
                    City\\
                    Country

\item[Phone:]       My phone number
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: labels not left aligned.

Comment: No, may be you don't understand the question (or may be that's me)